# i18n grails e jquery com idiomas diferentes

Tags: jquery, i18n, grails

Estou usando o recurso de internacionalização de idiomas (i18n) em um projeto Grails. Uma parte das tags é inserida diretamente nos arquivos .gsp e outra parte está nos scripts JS (Jquery/Bootstrap). Estes que estão nos scripts precisam usar uma lib jquery de terceiros. O recurso do Grails verifica o idioma do sistema. Logo, se o sistema e o navegador estiverem configurados com idiomas diferentes, o site vai exibir uma parte dos textos em um idioma e a outra parte no outro idioma. Para tentar contornar este problema, tentei ler o idioma do sistema usando jQuery, daí comparar com o idioma do navegador e igualar ambos,  mas aparentemente o comando para verificar o idioma do sistema  não funciona (testado em mac, win, android, no FF, Chrome, Safari)

```
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
var systemLang = navigator.systemLanguage;
console.log( userLang + " : " + systemLang );
```

Então preciso de ajuda para deixar os idiomas iguais, seja pelo Jquery, seja pelo Grails. Alguém saberia como fazer isto?

Comment: Na minha opinião, não use jquery para verificar que tipo de linguagem o browser está usando... verifique a documentacao do graisl: `http://guides.grails.org/grails_i18n/guide/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

Bom eu faco da seguinte maneira.
No meu layout eu coloco a seguinte tag no HEADER

```
<g:set var="lang" value="${session.'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE'}"/>
```

E em todas as minhas mensagens o coloco o seguinte codigo.

```
<g:message code='CODIGO MSG' lang='${lang}'/>
```

Assim o mesmo ira identificar automaticamente o idioma do usuario.

Eu mantenho e prefiro utilizar o idioma do navegador.

Caso voce queira voce pode implementar algo para o usuario que informe o idioma do mesmo para que seja possivel customizar o sistema.